# Vscode failing to comment in my JavaScript lines when using the comment in/out shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Start: `var x = 3;`

I select the line and press `ctrl` + `shift` + `7`

Result: `// var x = 3;`  (works as expected)

I select the line again and again press `ctrl` + `shift` + `7`

Result:  `// // var x = 3;`  (does **NOT** work as expected)

Desired Result: `var x = 3;`  (This works when doing css and html comments, only not when doing js comments)

When using the text editor Atom, I get the desired result, however, when using Vscode, it doesnt work.

**Atom > vscode ???** or what am I missing

Comment: try using: ```ctrl``` + ```/```

Comment: @Dolimight didnt work

Comment: Open the command input. Windows: Ctrl + Shift + P. Mac: Command + Shift + P.
Type in "keyboard" and select "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts".
Find "Toggle Line Comment". Try that shortcut. Otherwise I would reinstall vscode

Comment: @Dolimight thx, I added that one to ctrl + shift + 7 aswell and it works! Now both that and "add line comment" uses the same command though. Is it possible to unbind "add line comment" or does it not matter?

Comment: Too Bad, now I got the same problem as you after the update, before it was smart to detect on which part of HTML I am. The comment line will vary if inside <script> or <style> or inside and html tag it automatically adopts and comments properly now it became dumb that comment inside a script becomes html default comment <!-- --> 

Hope someone figures out how to roll it back from being smart again

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed Jinja plugin on you VS Code which creates conflict on commenting Javascripts. It does not work by disabling so you may need to uninstall it completely.